# Insert, Delete, and Edit Data in DataGridView using single Update Button in Vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to have a add, delete, and edit function in Vb.net by using one update button and changing the values in the datagridview manually then hitting update. However, I get an error stating
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified"

Any Ideas? The error comes next to the da.Update(changes)

Also in the above code not shown in my code I have load_data() in the private form1_load sub.

Here is code:

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataSet

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim changes As New DataSet
    changes = dt.GetChanges
    If changes IsNot Nothing Then
        da.Update(changes)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Tables(0)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub load_data()
    Using connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vbconnectionfinal;Integrated Security=True")

        da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From TrueTrack", connection)
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Tables(0)

    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is da declared?  As per the error message, are you specifying an update command?

Comment: da is declared just above my code in the question, it didn't go into the code box for some reason. As to specifying update command it is supposed to fill based off the updated dataset I believe or is supposed to, unless I messed that part up

Comment: The `SqlDataAdapter` constructor does not create any default INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands. Every command should be specified explicitly.

Comment: Chuck a breakpoint on the da.Update line and inspect the property to confirm maybe?

Comment: Check if my answer helps you handle this issue and if it helps, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If not, please provide more details here.

Comment: @Xingyu Zhao  The code you offered has no errors but doesn't quite do what I am looking for. I want the update command to actually be able to save the changed data in the dataset so that when I stop and start the code once again my dataset still the saved changes. As of now it updates the changes but does not save it so when I restart the code the dataset is reset back to its default start. Sorry for not responding sooner and I appreciate your time as it has helped. If you have any ideas of how to make this work or If I am doing something incorrect please let me know. Thank You!

Comment: @PasskyyCode I have given my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70793184/problem-in-vb-net-visual-studio-using-update-command/70797207#70797207), you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `SqlCommandBuilder` but not associating it with a `SqlDataAdapter`, so what's the point? The whole purpose of a command builder is to automatically generate action commands when you call `Update` on a data adapter. When you create your data adapter, create the command builder immediately after and associate the two, which you would do by passing the data adapter as an argument to the constructor of the command builder.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataSet
Dim connection = New SqlConnection("connection string")
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim changes As New DataSet
    changes = dt.GetChanges
    If changes IsNot Nothing Then
        da.Update(changes)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Tables(0)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub load_data()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * From TrueTrack", connection)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Tables(0)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    load_data()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```