# How to add Row to DataGridView in Visual Basic (Visual Studio)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, row

I want to be able to add a new row to my already existing DataGridView through the use of a button. How do I add this? (Using Visual Basic on Visual Studio)

Here is the Code Filling the DataGridView.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(PlaceHolder for String)
    Dim Table As New DataTable()
    
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TrackMain$", connection)
   
    Adapter.Fill(Table)
    
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table
    bind_data()

End Sub
```

Comment: It depends on how the DataGridView is populated in the first place. You can help us help you by adding that code.

Comment: Okay just added the Code, hopefully that helps, thanks. I am filling datagridview with sql database. Also the bind data is for a separate function and does not matter for the population of the grid. @djv

Comment: Great. So add a row to the DataTable and rebind. See how the question changes? Actually you need to know how to add a row to a DataTable, not add a row to a DataGridView. It changes depending on how it's populated. Always supply enough information to make the question answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind_data()` method seems to come from [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797207/12666543).

If you want to add a new empty row, just edit it directly on DataGridView.
For example:
[image]

To add a new row with data, you can use DataTable:

```
dt.Rows.Add(...)
```

Comment: Thank You, did not realize how simple of a problem this was!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a DataTable as a datasource, simply add a row to it before you bind

```vb
Dim toInsert = Table.NewRow()
Table.Rows.Add(toInsert)
```

If you are doing in a place other than where the initial binding is done, you should first retrieve the DataTable, then add, and rebind

```vb
Dim Table = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
Dim toInsert = Table.NewRow()
Table.Rows.Add(toInsert)
DataGridView1.DataSource = Table
bind_data()
```

Comment: I think there is an issue with my datasource possibly and its value? I am getting this error.  : 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable. (I could show you my entire code if it helps)

Comment: Maybe it's in `bind_data()`. Because `Dim Table As New DataTable() ... DataGridView1.DataSource = Table` shows it's exactly a DataTable